# how do I search a word in a webpage

Tags: java

how do I search for existence of a word in a webpage given its url say "www.microsoft.com". Do I need to download this webpage to perform this search ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make http request on web page and grab all its content after that you can search necessary words in it, below code might help you to do so.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL url;
        URLConnection urlConnection;
        DataOutputStream outStream;
        DataInputStream inStream;

        // Build request body
        String body =
        "fName=" + URLEncoder.encode("Atli", "UTF-8") +
        "&lName=" + URLEncoder.encode("Þór", "UTF-8");

        // Create connection
        url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
        urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        ((HttpURLConnection)urlConnection).setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+ body.length());

        // Create I/O streams
        outStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        inStream = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        // Send request
        outStream.writeBytes(body);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

        // Get Response
        // - For debugging purposes only!
        String buffer;
        while((buffer = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(buffer);
        }

        // Close I/O streams
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception cought:\n"+ ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i know how i would do this in theory - use cURL or some application to download it, store the contents into a variable, then parse it for whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to download page content and search inside it for what you want. And if it happens that you want to search the whole microsoft.com website then you should either write your own web crawler, use an existing crawler or use some search engine API like Google's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to download the page, and, to make sure to get the complete content, you'll want to execute scripts and include dynamic content - just like a browser.

We can't "search" something on a remote resource, that is not controlled by us and no webservers offers a "scan my content" method by default.

Most probably you'll want to load the page with a browser engine (webkit or something else) and perform the search on the internal DOM structure of that engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the search yourself, then obviously you have to download the page.
If you're planning on this approach, i recommend [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) (unless you want a simple substring search)

Or you could have a webservice that does it for you. You could request the webservice to `grep` the url and post back its results.

Comment: So is it to possible to make a web service that gives me the result whether a particular string is present in webpage given its url ??

Comment: @Syed, Sure, why not? Look at Gabe's Answer, you might already have access to them...

Comment: yep, It was a nice one i looked into it. I found APIs for retrieving results, image results etc.. But cud u suggest me an API for my purpose i.e., to search for existence of a word in the link

Comment: @Syed, I'm sorry, i haven't much info on that...you're better off reading some documentation on the Search Engine API's (Google,Bing,Yahoo)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a search engine's API. I believe Google and Bing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251056.aspx) have ones you can use.